# Android Studio to obtain user's location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

```
LatLng Barcelona = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(41.3818)), Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(2.1685)));
    // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(Barcelona).zoom(12).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition
                            (cameraPosition ));
```

I'm using Goole Maps APIs in Android Studio Activity, I want to get the user's location, and replace the variable "Barcelona" with the user's location so that the camera focuses on the user's location, thanks!!!!

Comment: Do you want to replace the marker? or please some more info

Comment: @EAMax i want to replace the Barcelona value for user's location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get location only once when activity started you can use following code.

First of all create FusedLocationProviderClient object as below:

```
FusedLocationProviderClient  fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this);
```

After creating object you can call getLastLocation() method for getting users location only once.

```
fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            CameraPosition.Builder builder = new CameraPosition.Builder();
                            builder.tilt(30);
                            builder.zoom(18f);
                            builder.target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.build();
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

If your app need continuously track location, it can deliver more relevant information to the user.

```
 LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
            mLocationCallback,
            null /* Looper */);
```

Your onCreate look like that

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// ...

mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            // Update UI with location data
            // ...
        }
    };
};
}
```

For further information explore the android documentation

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: how can I apply this in  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(Barcelona).zoom(12).build(); ??? i can't replace "barcelona"

Comment: just do all this stuff in onLocationChanged() method and you only need to change target() parameters as below: 
`CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).zoom(12).build();`

Comment: and if I want to do it without the location change?, at the beginning of the activity, because onLocationChanged() only is called when the location is changed

Comment: I think you want to get location only once when activity started and you are not intrested in location updates (Correct me if i am wrong) and for just getting location only once you can use fusedlocationprovider api. Let me update answer with this code. @FairyBand